# Why browser prepends a space while inserting key value pairs in cookies through javascript

Tags: javascript, cookies

I wrote a very simple javascript code to insert cookies :

```js
// setting the cookie value
function setCookie(cookieName, cookieValue) {
        document.cookie ='prasik=bihari';
        document.cookie ='pintu=tiwari';
        document.cookie = cookieName + "=" + cookieValue;
        document.cookie ='mykey=myvalue';
    }


// retrieving the cookie value
function getCookie(cookieName)
{
    var cookies = document.cookie.split(";");
    //printing the cookie array on console in developer tools
    console.debug(cookies);
    for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
        var cookie = cookies[i];
        var index = cookie.indexOf("=");
        var key = cookie.substr(0, index);
        var val = cookie.substr(index + 1);
        if (key == cookieName)
        return val;
    }
}

setCookie('firstName', 'Glenn');
var firstName = getCookie('pintu');
//this prints undefined as it fails to get the key 'pintu' which has been converted to ' pintu'
console.debug(firstName);

firstName = getCookie(' pintu');
//prints the correct value
console.debug(firstName);
```

Inside the `getCookie` method whenever I split the cookies using `;` character then developer tools shows me a space before the name of all the keys in the array except the first one:

[image]

So I fail to fetch the cookie value with the actual key `'pintu'` I had user while inserting the cookie. Instead when I use `' pintu'`, I get the value. Can someone explain this strange behavior or I'm making a mistake in my program?

**P.S.** I'm getting this behavior on Chrome as well as firefox.

Answer (score 1):

when you do `document.cookie` more times a space is added. so you must make the separation including that space.

```js
document.cookie.split("; ");
```